# How to grep Git commit messages or diffs for a keyword and output the file names that are changed (aggregated)?

Tags: git, grep, git-log

I'm trying to find all commits that contain a specific word in their commit message or diffs (on changes) from the beginning to the end of the project and **to list** all files where these changes (that contain this specific word) have occured.

For example, when I try

`git log -G"keyword" --name-only >log.txt`

it shows all commit messages one by one and the files that contain in their diffs the `"keyword"`.

But, instead I would like to have only the list of files (without repetition) in an output file (and/or possibly then the commit messages together).

Is any way to do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem can be solved by adding a [`--grep`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---grepltpatterngt) instead. This will help you find the commit messages with the expression you specify in the `grep` sequence.

Best

Comment: Even when I use `--grep` I receive quite the same output.  My intention is to have all files listed, as output, that occure on all commits that contain that keyword in the commit message or diff log. :/